# Hadoop maps but not reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I start a MapReduce job on my server the job will get to map 100% reduce 0% and then hang.

Opening up the web console shows that all the map jobs have completed and there is 1 "NEW" reduce but 0 "RUNNING" reduces.

The console output for the job is:

```
15/01/22 10:26:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/01/22 10:26:01 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/01/22 10:26:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/01/22 10:26:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1421950773318_0001
15/01/22 10:26:04 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1421950773318_0001 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/01/22 10:26:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1421950773318_0001/
15/01/22 10:26:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1421950773318_0001
15/01/22 10:26:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1421950773318_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/01/22 10:26:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/01/22 10:26:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

I am running:

- 64 bit CentOS release 6.4
- Hadoop 2.2.0-gphd-3.1.0.0

Comment: This could be your code or your environment. First, make sure that the word count example works. http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

Comment: You were attempted run a example job or code of yourself? I see some WARN and deprecations messages. Please post your code, at least the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the wordcount example on [wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)

The example did not work but I was able to fix my problem by allocating less memory for the reduce operation.